# Is it acceptable to work on my business during lunch/before work?

Tags: lunch, break-time

I am a software developer full time, as well as a wedding photographer on weekends. I normally arrive to work 20 minutes early, and leave 15 minutes late. My lunch breaks are 30 minutes long.

Is it acceptable practice for me to work on my wedding business (writing articles, answering emails etc) during my 30 minute lunch break, and before 9am in the office?

Comment: You could always ask your boss...

Comment: Sure, but some people might say *say* something is acceptable but *think* something different

Comment: Well, then you're dealing with a dishonest person... email, then you have it documented...

Comment: Where do you live? There might be legal issues (such as being required to take an actual break rather than just switching jobs for a bit)

Comment: As @Erik pointed out, please add a location tag.

Answer (score 11):

Policies included in your employee manual, or asking human resources specifically, can help you if you can proceed.

Normally though, you can proceed with your own business as long as :

1. You do not spend company time on this.
2. Your business does not conflict with the interests of the company.
3. Your business is not illegal in any fashion.
4. Your business will not impede your current responsibilities in any way.
5. You aren't using company resources (including computers) to do non-company things. Depending on the company, this can become a sticking point, for some

Comment: 5. You aren't using company resources (including computers) to do non-company things.  Depending on the company, this can become a sticking point, for some.

Comment: I'd extend "You do not spend company time on this" to "You do not use company resources for this" - resources including printing, computers, and internet... Some companies might ignore computer and internet usage for "personal" things, but others could see it as an actionable breach.

Comment: @Steve-O point added sir.

Comment: @HorusKol point is the same with Steve-O's, sir.  Still thanks

Comment: yeah, we submitted at the same time...

Comment: I'll just add that you should consider avoiding even the appearance of using company resources.

Answer (score -1):

From personal experience, as long as your using your own personal time and resources (and not using any company resources) then you should be OK. Hope that helps!

Comment: This could be a comment (a good one) rather than an answer. Could you please elaborate a bit more so future users get benefit from your answer?

Comment: Not ever OK without getting permission from your company first. In some instances working on personal outside businesses at your company can get you fired or they can claim the rights to the work.